# Drupal EVA module : Entity Content Settings not found in views

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I have downloaded and enabled [EVA module](http://drupal.org/project/eva). In views interface, I need the "Entity Content Settings" option under the Advanced area. However, it's not showing up.

Where I am making mistake?

Comment: I also got the same problem are you able to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

It show add EVA view display,show do (admin/structure/views/add new views/add/EVA filed)